# How to remove result part of a LDAP search - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to remove part of the a LDAP Search result and put into a string.

```
def login(username, password):
  try:
    l.simple_bind_s(username, password)
    base = "OU=Locations,DC=mydoamin,DC=com"

  criteria = "(&(objectClass=user)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Office)(whenCreated>=20180510000000.0Z))"  
  attributes = ['sAMAccountName', 'whenCreated']
  result = l.search_s(base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, criteria, attributes)
  r = str(result[0][1])
  print(r)

  except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
     return False
  return True

login(username,password)
```

The output is the follow:

```
{'whenCreated': [b'20180510154608.0Z'], 'sAMAccountName': [b'guimarme']}
```

So, I'd like to get just the result from whenCreated attribute '20180510154608.0Z' into a string and sAMAccountName attribute 'guimarme' into a string.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: `when_created = r['whenCreated'][0]`

Comment: Oh yeah, it worked:
when_created = str(r['whenCreated'][0]).replace("'",'').replace('b','')
  login = str(r['sAMAccountName'][0]).replace("'",'')
  print(str(when_created))
  print(str(login[1:]))

Comment: The `b'..'` you see aren't in the string, they are python's way of displaying a `bytes` object that has not been decoded instead of a string. For the date, if you want a string, `when_created = r['whenCreated'][0].decocde('ascii')` should do, but I'm not completely sure what encoding to use for sAMAccountName. Now that I look at it, I can't imagine why the API doesn't decode for you. Its the one that knows.

Answer (score 0):

print str(result[0][1]['whenCreated'][0])

print str(result[0][1]['sAMAccountName'][0])